# Matrix equation: solving $AB(A^{-1})(D^T)(C-1 )= E$ for $D$

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

The question is: Assuming that all the following matrices are of the same size and nonsingular, solve $AB(A^{-1})(D^T)(C-1 )= E$ for matrix $D$.

So far I got to $D^T = EC(B^{-1})$, but I do not know if it would be $D=[EC(B^{-1})]^{-T}$,  or  $D=[EC(B^{-1})]^T$, or even something else?

Answer (score 1):

Think again! Matrices do not commute in general. So what you should get is
$$
D^{T} = A B^{-1} A^{-1} C,
$$
and then transpose, which inverts the order of the factors.

(I have taken $E$ to be the identity matrix, if it's another generic matrix, then you get $D^{T} = A B^{-1} A^{-1} E C$.)

Comment: But cant I cancel out the A's?

Comment: Not in general. As I said, you are not guaranteed that $A B = B A$. Consider for example the matrices $A = \begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$. Then $A^{-1} = A$, and $A B A^{-1} = A B A = \begin{bmatrix}2&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix} \ne B$.

Comment: Oh I got it Thanks for your help!!!